# Ringworld character controller

Tags: unity, physics, movement, character

So, I'm making a sort of physics simulation in Unity involving a spinning ring to generate "gravity", and I have the ring and everything, but I've hit a snag: I have no idea how to make a character controller that can handle walking on spheres and in rings in about the same way.

My question is this: How do I create a character controller that walks equally well on a sphere and the inside of a ring? I don't need someone to write the whole thing for me, but if you could help me understand the logic behind it, or clue me into some of the methods that might be helpful, it would be really appreciated.

If it helps to know, I'm using Unity3D, and I write my code in C#.

Comment: I think you'll likely have a much easier time if you don't actually spin the ring, but instead keep it stationary and spin the background around it, adding forces to simulate centripetal / coriolis effects. Is that an option in your case?

Comment: @DMGregory I plan to have stationary, non-rotating spheres and/or platforms to walk on outside of rings, so in my case, it might be easier to actually make this controller work on the moving surface than to fake the motion. If it was just the ring, I would be all over just rotating the background.